# Using multiple Goroutines on Go Tour Equivalent Binary Trees

Tags: go, goroutine

When attempting to solve tree walk portion of the [Equivalent Binary Trees](http://tour.golang.org/#72) problem in the Go Tour, the obvious solution is to use [recursion](https://code.google.com/p/go-tour/source/browse/solutions/binarytrees.go). Other solutions, such as a closure, are provided in answers to the [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224042/go-tour-exercise-equivalent-binary-trees) on how to solve the problem.

My original thought was to use a Goroutine for each step of the walk. Isn't this a better, more Go-onic (what's the Go equivalent of Pythonic?) solution? The problem is I couldn't figure out how to either A) close the channel after the tree has been walked, or B) signal in some other way that the tree walk completed. An earlier [example](http://tour.golang.org/#69) uses 2 channels, one for data and one for a quit signal. Passing a second channel doesn't fit with the problem definition, and the root issue of when the walk is finished is still present. Is there an elegant solution with a Goroutine for each walk step, or is recursion the best solution?

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    if t != nil {
        go Walk(t.Left, ch)
        ch <- t.Value
        go Walk(t.Right, ch)
    }
    //Done with this node, how do I know when all are done?
}
```

Comment: Funny you should ask, a recent talk at Gophercon by Andrew Gerrand (of the Go team) touched on this: http://talks.golang.org/2014/go4gophers.slide#27

Answer (score 1):

Using a goroutine for each step of the walk will not work. Entirely apart from not knowing when you can close the channel (which I don't know of a good way to solve), you are not guaranteed to get the ordering you want. For example, the following code:

```
go fmt.Println(1)
go fmt.Println(2)
go fmt.Println(3)
```

Could print any of 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, or 321 depending on how the scheduler chooses to run those goroutines. This means that your `Walk` implementation is no longer going to give you the values in the correct order.

Goroutines are only the right answer when there is actually something you want to do concurrently; given that the output to the channel has to be strictly ordered there is no concurrency to exploit in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

```
func internalWalk(t *tree.Tree, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan int) {
    wg.Add(1)
    if t != nil {
        go Walk(t.Left, ch)
        ch <- t.Value
        go Walk(t.Right, ch)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    internalWalk(t, &wg, ch)
    wg.Wait()
    //they are all done now, do something here
}
```