# Equivalent sorted binary tree In Java

Tags: java, algorithm, go

I am learning `Go` and in this [tutorial](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/7), concurrency and channels can be used to complete this exercise: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24580091/9690075).

And I try to solve this by `Java`. The solution I can think of is to use temporary data structure to store the results of the in-order traversal of these two trees, and then compare.

For example, I use a `StringBuilder` to store the result of the in-order traversal and then compare(Notice that we're comparing sorted binary trees):

```
    public boolean equivalentBST(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        StringBuilder pSb = new StringBuilder();
        walk(pSb, p);
        StringBuilder qSb = new StringBuilder();
        walk(qSb, q);
        return pSb.compareTo(qSb) == 0;
    }

    private void walk(StringBuilder sb, TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        walk(sb, node.left);
        sb.append(node.val);
        walk(sb, node.right);
    }
```

Testcase:

```
        TreeNode p = new TreeNode(9);
        TreeNode p2 = new TreeNode(8);
        TreeNode p3 = new TreeNode(7);
        p.left = p2;
        p2.left = p3;

        TreeNode q = new TreeNode(9);
        TreeNode q2 = new TreeNode(8);
        TreeNode q3 = new TreeNode(7);
        q3.right = q2;
        q.left = q3;

        System.out.println(equivalentBST(q, p)); // output true
```

I want to know is there any other better way to solve this by `Java`?

Comment: An `(Array)BlockingQueue` with a capacity of 1 maybe + threads. In effect you only need co-routines as in the go language.

Comment: I presume Morris traversal would also be a good way to evaluate equivalence between 2 trees' structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk both trees at the same time and compare their elements immediately without using a `StringBuilder`.

Something along the lines:

```
public boolean equivalentBST(TreeNode node1, TreeNode node2) {
    var stack1 = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    var stack2 = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

    while (true) {
        while (node1 != null) {
            stack1.add(node1);
            node1 = node1.left;
        }
        while (node2 != null) {
            stack2.add(node2);
            node2 = node2.left;
        }
        if (stack1.isEmpty() || stack2.isEmpty())
            return stack1.isEmpty() && stack2.isEmpty();
        node1 = stack1.remove(stack1.size() - 1);
        node2 = stack2.remove(stack2.size() - 1);
        if (node1.val != node2.val)
            return false;
        node1 = node1.right;
        node2 = node2.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your answer! But your solution seems to be to compare whether there are the same structure and values, I updated the test case, you can take a look

Comment: @zysaaa you're right. We would have to walk both trees at the same time, but not synchronously. I will think about a fix to the code.

Comment: @zysaaa please check now. The current code uses two stacks for navigating the two trees independently, instead of relying on recursion (and the call stack).

Comment: A recursive approach is also possible, but would be less understandable.